# Exact derivation for finding k-means from Gaussian Mixtures

Tags: clustering, mixed-model, k-means, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am having difficulty in deriving k-means from Mixture of Gaussians. I am following the notation from Bishop (2006), Section 9.3.2:

Suppose we have : 
$$
p(\mathbf{x}| \boldsymbol{\mu}_k, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_k ) = \frac{1}{(2\pi \epsilon )^{1/2}} \exp \left( \frac{ -1 }{ 2 \epsilon } \| \mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu} \|^2 \right)
$$
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[  \ln p \left(  \mathbf{X, Z} | \boldsymbol{\mu, \Sigma, \pi} \right)  \right] = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \gamma(z_{nk}) \left \lbrace  \ln \pi_k + \ln \mathcal{N} (  \mathbf{x}_n | \boldsymbol{\mu}_k, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_k ) \right\rbrace   
$$
[image]

[image]

[image]

It has been claimed that if we take the limit $ \epsilon \rightarrow 0 $ we will have:

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[  \ln p \left(  \mathbf{X, Z} | \boldsymbol{\mu, \Sigma, \pi} \right)  \right] = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{K} r_{nk} \| \mathbf{x}_n - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k \|^2 + \text{const.}
$$

It is easy to show that $\gamma(z_{nk}) \rightarrow r_{nk}$. But it is not clear to me how to show the above equation. Can anyone help?

Comment: Draw superimposed graphs of $\exp(-(|x-\mu_i|/\epsilon)^2)$ for two different values of $\mu_i$.  What happens as $\epsilon$ shrinks towards $0$?  (A log-linear plot may help you see this better.)

Comment: Not clear on what you mean. Could you give more details?

Comment: First you have to fix the first line: there should be no "$\epsilon^2$", only $\epsilon$; and notice that neither $k$ nor $\Sigma_k$ appear on the right hand side--which means something is wrong.  On the second line it is unclear what connection the "$p$" on the left hand side has to do with the preceding $p$--they take different numbers of arguments. Therefore I have ignored most of this and focused on the definition of $\gamma$: it looks at the values of one Gaussian relative to the sum of all of them. If you have no intuition for how this behaves, *plot this function* and vary $\epsilon$.